# How insert statement works in open source akaunting script?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have downloaded an open source accounting script from akaunting.com. This source code is developed in Laravel. I am trying to add one more field in the items table, but I am not able to find the insert statement in this script.

Here is the controller code. After this I am not getting any idea.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $item = Item::create($request->input());

    // Upload picture
    if ($request->file('picture')) {
        $media = $this->getMedia($request->file('picture'), 'items');

        $item->attachMedia($media, 'picture');
    }

    $message = trans('messages.success.added', ['type' => trans_choice('general.items', 1)]);

    flash($message)->success();

    return redirect()->route('items.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a long search I got the solution.

In `app/models/common/item.php` we can add extra fields. The text box name and database column name should be the same.

```
protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'name', 'sku', 'description', 'sale_price', 'purchase_price', 'quantity', 'category_id', 'tax_id', 'enabled','expiry_date'];
```